# Android: Image does not appear

Tags: android, imageview

I have a pr0blem with the ImageView, I can not view my image and I would like to get my application to work perfectly. So can someone help me out :)

Code:

```
...
ImageView myimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);     
myimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img01));
Thread.sleep(500);
myimage.setImageDrawable(null);
Thread.sleep(700);
Button button2 = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.button2));
button2.setEnabled(true);
...
```

PS: Sorry my bad english!

Comment: I think you need to use a runOnUiThread.

Comment: Do you expect the image stays on screen during 500 ms and disappears after that?

Comment: I only want the image flashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Thread.sleep` to delay. This will sleep the UI thread and hang your app. Try [`View.postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29):

```
ImageView myimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
myimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img01));
myImage.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myimage.setImageDrawable(null);
        myImage.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Button button2 = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.button2));
                button2.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }, 700);
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not see the image because you are setting the drawable to null. remove that line of code and it will work. As an advice you should not used get drawable because that method has a memory leak, so you should use instead the setImageResource method